# What do these uGet settings (curl+aria2, aria2+curl) mean?

Tags: settings, uget

In uGet settings, plugins, I see the option called 'Plug-in matching order'.

Curl or aria2 can be selected as the active program that runs the download with two of the options; but what the other two do (curl+aria2, aria2+curl) ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are download engines for uGet.

You can use CURL or aria2 as the backend engine to do the download. These plugins provide different features so you can pick which one you want...or you can choose an order to use the plugins.

For example, if one plugin is faster for you then you can use that one and if you attempt to do a feature that it doesnt support it will move onto the next plugin to accomplish the task.

Comment: Side note: you should ask application specific questions on the project's preferred support website that way the developers are most likely to see the questions . . . - http://ugetdm.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3 (not all developers are as attentive as I am)

Comment: I am used with taking advantage of this site as a sort of knowledge-base for my ongoing (ubuntu-based) experience with Linux - and so I can come back later and find what I need, all in one place so to speak. But of course you are right. I will sign in on uget forum too.

Comment: I am surprised to see that, although most people (I think you too in one of your older posts here) praise aria2 before curl, after you showed me the new 1.99 version that has multi curl, multi curl seems faster than multi aria2, really the first time I am fully convinced that uGet is the answer to the (in)famous askubuntu question "What's the IDM alternative in Ubuntu?"